# Getting value in div and changing to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that gets values from the database and prints them inside a div:

```
<div class="number-string">
123456789
</div>
```

I'm hoping to pull that value inside .number-string and change that div to a link where the href would be "https://somelink.com/123456789"
All I have right now is

```
var getnumber = $('.number-string').text()
```

I can't figure out how to change that div and add in a variable to a link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `replaceWith()` method to replace the div with a link.

```
$('.number-string').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith(`<a href="https://somelink.com/${this.innerText}">${this.innerText}</a>`);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var trackingNum = $(".number-string");
function toLink(elem,link){
  let l1 = elem.text();
  elem.replaceWith(`<a href="${link}/${l1}">Click here</a>`);
}
toLink(trackingNum,'http://example');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number-string">
123456789
</div>
```